# Want to set the text into bottom of linearlayout inside a table row

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a layout like this:

```
  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titles1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstLine1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Row"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="2nd Row"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dji" >
    </ImageView>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I tried to set the 2nd row to the bottom of layout inside this table row, and that linearlayout would take the whole row space. I tried to adjust the parameters, but so far, I cannot make it.

Any suggestion? Is my layout OK? or other better choice?

It shows the layout like. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `layout_weight` attribute ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)). You can set the first and second `TextView` with fixed `height` and add one placeholder `View` with `height` set to `0` and `weight` set to `1`. I hope this will help :)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titles1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Row"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/palceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2nd Row"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. That is what I want, I need to learn more, and thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, happy to read this! If so, may I ask you to accept the answer :)

Comment: Without placeholder, just set the lineOne weight=0 and height="wrap_content", and lineTwo weight=1 and height="wrap_content" also worked.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your LinearLayout to a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/titles1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="First Row"
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="2nd Row"
        android:textSize="16sp">
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Or use weights on the LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titles1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="First Row"
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="2nd Row"
        android:textSize="16sp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```